# javascript THREE OrbitControls: doubleclick Object

Tags: javascript, three.js, double-click

I am using THREE.js and OrbitControls.js. I want to doubleclick an Object and then do stuff.
This is the code I am using. cube1 is the Object I want to doubleclick.

```
var projector = new THREE.Projector();

document.addEventListener('dblclick', ondblclick, false);

function ondblclick(event)
{               
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
    ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
    - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
    0.5);
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, 
                     vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( cube1 );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 )
    {
        alert("hit");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the code does not work.
I appreciate any help.
This is the camera I am using:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, WIDTH/HEIGHT, 0.1, 10000 );
        camera.position.z = 1500;
        camera.position.y = -1800;
        scene.add(camera);
```

And this is OrbitControls:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/gre9ubys/) Notice, that it's an example for double click with `THREE.Raycaster()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just corrected the ondblclick function

```
function ondblclick(event) {
    x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    dir = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, -1)
    dir.unproject(camera)

    ray = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, dir.sub(camera.position).normalize())
    var intersects = ray.intersectObject(sphere);
    if ( intersects.length > 0 )
    {
        alert("hit");
    }
}
```

Here is the working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/ddbTy/241/